# Linking one link to another in JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I want to link one link to another link. Basically I want to connect the red arrow head to the red line in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2theman/gmh9X/

I tried commenting out the following line in the joint.nojquery.js file as follows:

```
    if (this._viewUnderPointer && this._viewUnderPointer.model instanceof joint.dia.Link) {

            // Do not allow linking links with links.
            //this._viewUnderPointer = null;         <---- Commented this out.
        }
```

Although I was able to link one link to another after doing this, it resulted in unstable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Though not really an answer which solve your problem, I should mention that, I've seen a post in JointJS google forum (I don't have a link now) saying this is a feature they are planning to implement/release. So it's worth a wait. You should get better feedback from their Google group forum, I guess.